# Forex send orders using Python without Metatrader5

Tags: python, api, algorithmic-trading, forex, metatrader5

Need solutions to Forex order_send in Python.
using Metatrader5 its so easy:

```
import MetaTrader5 as mt5

            request = {
                "action": mt5.TRADE_ACTION_DEAL,
                "symbol": symbol,
                "volume": lot,
                "type": trade_type,
                "price": price,
                "tp": tp,
                "sl": sl,
            }

            result = mt5.order_send(request)
```

But for some reason I only have one Linux server now. My attempts to install MetaTrader 5 were completely unsuccessful (even after trying the Windows emulator).

[image]

Is there a way to Send my forex orders without using Metatrader5?

Thank you all

Comment: How did you install `Metatrader5` package for linux?

Comment: I said it in question, it's unsuccessful. I need a way to send orders without Metatrader

Comment: Sorry I meant python package.

Comment: Thank you for your attention .You made me doubt by asking. Did I make a mistake and is there a way to install it? After searching, I came to the conclusion that NO! (there is a suggestion to use wine, which I can not trust for online trading and scalp. Although the wine itself is not installed)

Answer (score 1):

`Metatrader5` Python package is only for Windows and cannot be installed on Linux. See https://www.mql5.com/en/forum/354796

So the only way to run MT on Linux is a Windows emulator. I run MT4 and MT5 in Ubuntu and macOS using Wine.

Probably the good way is to ask about your problems with installing MT5 using Wine at https://superuser.com/.

Installing Python under Windows emulator is a separate problem.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But Is there a way to Send my forex orders without using Metatrader5?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Metatrader uses custom protocol to communicate with the broker and Python package communicates with Metatraer program.

Comment: Does it mean there is no Forex trading bot has been ever made in among Linux users? Let me be a little hopeful  :(((

Comment: You can take a look at MetaApi https://metaapi.cloud

Answer (score 0):

you can use mt5linux package, it's a package that work in the same manner on linux.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).